# How does DXViewer center an object?

Tags: c++, directx

In DXViewer it centers the .X object.  I tried to go and read the code but it was too complicated.  Do you have any idea how they do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well its easy to work out the center of a mesh.  (**Edited**)Averaging the extreme points (ie top, left, front and bottom, right back) of the mesh will give you the center.

Most of the time the mesh will already be built around the origin however so I'd be surprised if they do this.

Comment: Wouldn't averaging out the positions just find the average position of all the vertices? I would have thought to find the true center you would need the most extreme points (most left, most right, most top, most bottom, most deep, least deep) and average those points, since if there are more vertices on the right side of the model the average will weight itself that way which would be off center...

Comment: @meds:  Yes, you are in fact completely correct.  In most cases, though, the difference between both methods would be very slight.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the directx viewer actually centers a mesh, it just draws it as the points are sent in.